# Regular Expression PHP to replace <textarea/>

Tags: php, regex, textarea, preg-replace

I want to replace  with 
For example I have this one:

```
 <textarea type="text" style="height: 30px; width: 144px;" name="a" id="a" value=""/>
```

and I want it to become:

```
 <textarea type="text" style="height: 30px; width: 144px;" name="a" id="a" value=""></textarea>
```

I using this regular expression:

```
 preg_replace('!<textarea.*/>!', '<textarea.*></textarea>', $text);
```

but is not working. I am quite new to regular expressions so it would be very nice if someone could help me with this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: [Don't use regular expressions to parse (X)HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/112968)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$text = '<textarea type="text" style="height: 30px; width: 144px;" name="a" id="a" value=""/>';

$text = preg_replace('/<textarea(.*?)\/>/', 
                     '<textarea$1></textarea>', $text);
print $text;
```

Prints:

```
<textarea type="text" style="height: 30px; width: 144px;" name="a" id="a" value=""></textarea>
```

Comment: RegEx shouldn't be necessary here

Comment: @RoyalBg Please, explain, why

Comment: First of all the goal is pretty simple for this, which seems overkill, and second as @knittl stated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @RoyalBg As the 2-nd answer from your page says: "it's sometimes appropriate to parse a limited, known set of HTML". In general, HTML is not a regular language and shouldn't be parsed with regexes. But for this limited case, regex will give a correct result.

Answer (score 0):

$try this code:

```
$s= '<textarea type="text" style="height: 30px; width: 144px;" name="a" id="a" value=""/>';
echo $a= str_replace("/>","></textarea>",$s);
```

Comment: This is ok, if there are no other elements, ending with />, like <br/>, that will be replaced to <br></textarea>

Comment: Thanks but I have many elements ending with />. This example is just a part of a bigger text. So this is not what I want.